# Force a new line in Sphinx text

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have Sphinx text in the following format in source code:

```
Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 4
```

I would like Line 4 to be rendered in HTML on a separate physical line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a hard line break as follows:

```
.. # define a hard line break for HTML
.. |br| raw:: html

   <br />
```

You should define such aliases in a `prolog.inc` and reference it in you Sphinx configuration file.

Here is a usage example:

```
My first line |br|
My second line
```

Comment: This is a bad answer, since this hack will break when generating any document format but HTML. @banderlog013's reply has the proper solution.

Answer (score 29):

Use [line blocks](https://rest-sphinx-memo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ReST.html#line-blocks):

```
| Line 1
| Line 2
| Line 3
| Line 4
```

Will produce:

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4

Comment: As of 6/2021, can confirm this answer worked for me.

Comment: does not work. looks like a quote now, with all lines indented

Comment: it still works as in the documentation (link provided above)

Comment: Throws an error in VS Code rst previewer

Answer (score 2):

I had to use directive line block, nothing else worked for me.

```
.. line-block::
   Line 1
   Line 2
```

Comment: Can you eleborate what went wrong when using the line block syntax (`| line 1 \n| line 2`)?

Answer (score 1):

The solutions **user14678546** and **Paebbels** also work for tables:

Using [line blocks](https://rest-sphinx-memo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ReST.html#line-blocks) in tables is inconstant, not pretty, as well as it leaves a blank/additional line break at the end, resulting in ex. 3 lines but only the first 2 lines have text.

Here is an example of a line break in a table of reStructuredText (only for html):

```
.. table:: Truth table for "not"
  :width: 20%
  :widths: 1 3 1

  =====  =====    =====
  A      not A    Note
  =====  =====    =====
  False  True     Text here
  True   False    Comment here
         False
  False  True     Text here |br| line break in table here
  True   False
  =====  =====    =====

.. |br| raw:: html

     <br>
```

Using `|br|` inline in text in a table, results in a line brake in a single cell of text (in html): [Table with line break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFAoz.png)

It also works for csv tables.

Comment: "This work-around also works for table's!" What workaround are you referring to?

Comment: Of using |br| inline in text in a table, resulting in a line brake in a single cell of text (in html). That might not have been clear enough.

Comment: Yes, avoid unclear references such as "This work-around...". An answer should stand on its own. Stack Overflow is not a traditional discussion forum.

Comment: Yes. I'm new to this (which I guess you have figured out) and I really wanted to quote or referee to "user14678546" or "Paebbels" answer, but didn't find that option. Or should I have putt it as a comment of "user14678546" or "Paebbels" answer? But then I guess that I didn't have the option of giving an example formatted as code? Or should I even have created a new question and then answer my own question?

Comment: It is not forbidden to mention other answers. Just make sure it is clear which answer you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Line 1 |br|
Line 2 |br|
Line 3 |br|
Line 4 |br|
```

At the end of the file you need to put:

```
.. |br| raw:: html

      <br>
```

Note: This does not work when making latex code.

Comment: It also fails with XML, OpenDocument, and manpage output.

Answer (score 0):

In the source code, just add extra empty line and it will do the job. for example:

```
    Line 1
    
    Line 2
    
    Line 3
```

Comment: This creates separate paragraphs. (Note that this also works well in table cells.) Depending on what is really intended, this may be the correct answer or not.